# Removing an item from the JList using ListModel as model type

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have the `JList` which is using `ListModel` and not the DefaultListModel. I don't want to change the type now because I am using this in many places. I want to remove a selected item from the same list. How do i do this? I am using the following code but its not working for me.

```
made_list.removeSelectionInterval(
    made_list.getSelectedIndex(), made_list.getSelectedIndex());
```

--EDIT--

I am using the following code when I create my list:

```
made_list = new javax.swing.JList();   
made_list.setModel(new DefaultListModel());
```

And then in the `JButton` mouseclick event, I am using the following code to remove the selected item from the list when the button is pressed

```
private void removeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    //made_list.removeSelectionInterval(made_list.getSelectedIndex(), 
    //made_list.getSelectedIndex());  
    System.out.println(made_list.getModel());  
    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)made_list.getModel();  
    model.remove(1);  
}
```

Comment: i am sorry but i am using NetBeans to draw the list component onto the panel. When i used getModel() i am getting javax.swing.JList$4@34f09710 and when i tried to typecast it to DefaultListModel i am getting the error  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$4 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel

Comment: Reformatted code; copyedited; please revert if incorrect. If you're _not_ using `DefaultListModel` then `ClassCastException` makes sense. You should be able to cast it to your custom model.

Comment: Please see edits made to my last answer, including my version of an SSCCE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

removeSelectionInterval removes nothing from the model or the list except the selection interval.  The list items remain unscathed. I'm afraid that you're either going to have to extend your ListModel and give it a removeItem(...) method as well as listeners and the ability to fire notifiers, etc... a la AbstractListModel -- quite a lot of work! If it were my money, though, I'd go the easy route and simply use a DefaultListModel for my model as it is a lot safer to do it this way, a lot easier, and will take a lot less time.  I know you state that you don't want to use these, but I think you'll find it a lot easier than your potential alternatives.

An example of an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) is something like this:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo1 {
   private String[] elements = {"Monday", "Tueday", "Wednesday"};
   private javax.swing.JList made_list = new javax.swing.JList();

   public Foo1() {
      made_list.setModel(new DefaultListModel());
      for (String element : elements) {
         ((DefaultListModel) made_list.getModel()).addElement(element);
      }

      JButton removeItemBtn = new JButton("Remove Item");
      removeItemBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            removeActionPerformed(e);
         }
      });

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(new JScrollPane(made_list));
      panel.add(removeItemBtn);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }

   private void removeActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("made_list's model: " + made_list.getModel());
      System.out.println("Model from a fresh JList: " + new JList().getModel());
      DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) made_list.getModel();
      if (model.size() > 0) {
         model.remove(0);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Foo1();
   }

}
```

Comment: I have created the List as DefaultListModel and when i use this DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)made_list.getModel(); to access the methods of DefaultListModel i am gettin the error

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JList$4 cannot be cast to javax.swing.DefaultListModel

Comment: @Deepak: let's see more of the offending code as an edit to your original post in this thread.  I suggest showing us where you set the list's model with your DefaultListModel object, and where you try to access this model and call it's methods.  It looks to me as if you're trying to cast a JList, not its model as a DefaultListModel, but we'll know for sure what you're doing when we see your code.

Comment: @Deepak: are you sure the two JLists are one and the same, that you don't have one declared in the class and another (the one with the DefaultListModel for model) declared in a constructor or method?  It will be hard to figure this out I think without compilable runnable code, but your whole program is likely too big and cumbersome to be much use to us. Consider creating and posting a small runnable program that shows your problem but has no extraneous code, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: +1 good working code. To remove the selected one an easy code change is required, to change the code:  `if (model.size() > 0)
         model.remove(0);` to this code:
   `if(made_list.getSelectedIndex() != -1)
         model.remove(made_list.getSelectedIndex());`
       
Just wondering, will you in this case have a problem if the view of the list is ordered differently then the model?

Comment: If so then you would have to use this code: `model.remove(model.indexOf(made_list.getSelectedValue()));`

Comment: @trashgod: Foo1 confirmed?  confused!

Comment: @HFOE: Sorry, that was a little cryptic.  I just meant that your program ran correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You've been given a link to different sections of the Swing tutorial in the past to help solve problems. This was done for a reason. It helps solve your current problem. It gives you a reference for future problems.

All you need to do is look at the Table of Contents for the Swing tutorial and you will find a section on "How to Use Lists" which has a working example that adds/removes items from a list. Please read the tutorial first.

Or if you can't remember how to find the Swing tutorial then read the JList API where you will find a link to the same tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
//First added  item into the list
DefaultListModel dlm1=new DefaultListModel();

listLeft.setModel(dlm1);

dlm1.addElement("A");
dlm1.addElement("B");
dlm1.addElement("C");

// Removeing element from list
Object[] temp=listRight.getSelectedValues();
if(temp.length>0)
{
for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
{

  dlm1.removeElement(temp[i]);

}
}
```

Comment: try to add some description to your code - it will help in better understanding of why this works